# Python2:I want to add some string in dict o/p

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

command= {'SEL': 'band','LATOR': '27.05','RAMP' : 'disabled'}

for key in command:
print(key, command[key])

o/p:-
SEL band
LATOR 27.05
RAMP disabled

Expected O/P:-
I want to add GHZ in LATOR:-
SEL band
LATOR 27.05GHz
RAMP disabled

Comment: Do you want to change your dictionary or do you want to change your output? And what didn't work when you tried to do it?

Comment: I want to change the o/p

Comment: I want to  add Ghz in lator value and output as 27.05GHz

Comment: What's a lator anyway, and why is it measured in GHz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, it modifies the output without actually changing the input dictionary:

```
for key in command:
    if key == 'LATOR':
        print(key, command[key] + 'GHz')
    else:
        print(key, command[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add GHz to your 'LATOR' key, you can use `command["LATOR"] += "GHz"`

Comment: Notice that this will modify the dictionary, I think that's not what OP wants.

Comment: but I am iterating the dict

Comment: OP says "I want to add Ghz in lator value" in a comment, but otherwise copying the entire dictionary before editing or your loop solution should work too

Answer (score 0):

## You can get your desired output by this code

```
command= {'SEL': 'band','LATOR': '27.05Ghz','RAMP' : 'disabled'}

for key in command:
    print(key, command[key])
```

Comment: I dont want to add in dict,I want in o/p as 27.05Ghz

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the question. Anyways, adding an if-else loop like stated about should work in that case.